# Getting user auth from email (not logged in)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

With the email of a user, I would like to get the user's id from firebase.auth() without the user being logged in. I am using VueJS for my code. Is there anyway to do this?

I have searched and found this for Node.JS but am unsure if it is the correct way to do it in VueJS as well.

```
admin
.auth()
.getUserByEmail(email)
.then((userRecord) => {
  // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
  console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
});
```

Is this the correct method for getting the uid just base on email (not logged in)
Thanks

Comment: He can using the Admin SDK and not the Web SDK.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct method for getting the uid just base on email (not logged in)

Short answer: Yes.

Below method will return the user *uid* based on its *email* using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/):

```
admin
  .auth()
  .getUserByEmail(email)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    return userRecord.getUid();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

Meanwhile, this method will fail if you are referring to another AUTH provider email address:

> Warning: For email lookup, you can only search the main (top level) email and not provider specific emails. For example, if a Facebook account with a different email facebookUser@example.com is linked to an existing user with email user@example.com, calling getUserByEmail("facebookUser@example.com") will yield no results whereas getUserByEmail("user@example.com") will return the expected user. In the case of the default "single account per email" setting, the first email used to sign in with will be used as the top level email unless modified afterwards. When "multiple accounts per email" is set, the main email is only set when a password user is created unless manually updated.

*Note: The Admin SDK is intended to be used within a secure environment, and should not generally be used within a web-based application client.*

Comment: To answer the question, you should instead suggest your current code as a HTTPS Cloud Function (a callable function is probably the better choice here). The OP is looking for a solution on the client side.

Comment: When the OP looks for the 'wrong' solution, it should be notified to re-consider its choices :)